# Dynamically creating fields bind to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am dynamically creating 2 text boxes on click of an add button. 
One for first name and one for last name.

Below is what I have in my model:

```
public List<UserName> FullName{ get; set; }
```

Below is what UserName type has associated with it:

```
public class UserName
{        
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName{ get; set; }
}
```

For the firstNames, I have the textbox name as firstName and for lastName I have the textbox name as lastName.  Not sure how to tie it all together to where when I submit, it will be shown as part of the FullName list

Comment: If your inputs are in your form, and they have a name, and are not disabled, submitting the form will send them to the backend, regardless of if they are dynamically created or not.  I've removed the `jquery` tag as this appears to be more focused on asking how to map the request query params to the domain elements.

Comment: You need to provide more code. Where  are you submitting the form? You don't know how to extract data from the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the indexing information for your `input`/`TextBox` in the view, so MVC model binder knows how to put them back in a list, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="[0].FirstName" value="" />
<input type="text" name="[0].LastName" value="" />

<input type="text" name="[1].FirstName" value="" />
<input type="text" name="[1].LastName" value="" />
```

Or you can use a loop:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].LastName)
}
```

See [Phil Haack's](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) article for more info.

---

*Note: I have renamed your public property names firstName/lastName to use PascalCase instead of camelCase.*